# How to take reference for a script using another script

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, multiplayer

Basically i want to make a multiplayer game, for which I have a player prefab

Here's it's contains

[image]

And I have a Gameobject outside this prefab which use reference player prefab CameraPos

[image]

[image]

I am using a script in Player prefab called MountObjects to add reference of Cam position which is outside of Player prefab

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class mountObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Orientation;
public GameObject Camera;
public Transform localCamera;
public PlayerCamera playerCamera;
public LinkCam linkcam;
 void Start()
 {
    playerCamera = GetComponent<PlayerCamera>();
    linkcam = GetComponent<LinkCam>();



    playerCamera.Orientation = Orientation.transform;
    linkcam.CamPosition = Camera;
 }
}
```

I want my script to add reference of CameraPos to CamCotainer, when my playerprefab is added by NetworkManager
Please ignore some values as i was testing the script
I am new to multiplayer games, so please help me

Comment: so what is the issue? theres no question here

Comment: I want to give reference to the LinkCam Script which is attacted to CamContainer, when my playerprefab spawns

Comment: so have shown you know how to get a reference to the linkcam script - what specifically is stopping you?

Comment: It is not getting reference from the script, i want to add reference to cam posttion(img3) using the my code, which is apparently not working

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication

Comment: im going to guess youre linkcam and playercamera are not on the same object as the script being run.

Comment: Yes they are separate objects

Comment: then thats why it doesnt work, getcomponent only gets it from the current object.

Comment: How should i do then??? @BugFinder

Comment: you need to find them - which while Overture didnt have enough information to give you a specific answer, has shown you how, perhaps a tutorial would benefit you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this would work in a prefab but to reference a script from another script you can do something like this:

First in the script that you want to reference the other script from create a variable that is the same type as the script to be referenced, which is its name:

```
private ScriptToBeReferencedName localScriptName;
```

Then assign the script to be referenced to this variable, can be done in start method

```
localScriptName  = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObject).GetComponent<ScriptToBeReferencedName>();
```

Then you can access any of the script methods or variable by: `localScriptName.methodname or localScriptName.variable`

Make sure any of the variable or methods you want to access are set to Public. You are essentialy treating the script you want to reference as any other component.